# How to redirect with nginx

Tags: nginx, forwarding

I have some http servers running in different ports, but I want to access them this way:

```
192.168.178.42:80/foo   to access   192.168.178.42:8080
192.168.178.42:80/asdf  to access   192.168.178.42:12321
```

etc.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible.

for example:

```
 server {
  listen 80;
  location /foo {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.178.42:8080;
  }
  location /asdf {
   proxy_pass http://192.168.178.42:12321;
  }
 }
```